# Displaying specific HABTM data on a user's info page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a mock of wikpedia. My app has standard users, premium users, and admins. Premium users can create private wikis and add collaborators. Collaborators can be standard users. I've set up my collaborators migration to have user_id and wiki_id. I can't figure out how I would display on a user's page the wikis that they are collaborators on. I've displayed wikis that they've created- that was easy. I've started a method in my wiki.rb, `def collabs` that is what I think should collect the collaborator info for each user, but I don't know how I would use this in my users show.html.erb file. I'm pretty new to rails and I've really only had experience with simple do loops to display info. For example, this is how I'm displaying a user's wikis:

```
<% @user.wikis.each do |w| %>
  <%= link_to w.title, w, :class => 'rq-link' %>
    <% if w.private? %>
      <small>(private)</small>
    <% end %>
    <br />
<% end %>
```

Here is my wiki.rb:

```
class Wiki < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  scope :alphabetical, -> { order("title ASC") }
  scope :visible_to, -> (user) { (user.admin? || user.premium?) ? all :where(private: false) }

  has_many :users, through: :collaborators
  has_many :collaborators

  def collaborator_for(user)
    collaborators.where(user_id: user.id).first
  end

  def users
    collaborators.collect(&:user)
  end

  def collabs
    users.collect(&:collaborator)
  end

end
```

Here is m User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :wikis
  has_many :collaborators

  after_initialize :default_role
  enum role: [:standard, :premium, :admin]

  def default_role
    self.role ||= :standard
  end

end
```

Collaborator.rb:

```
class Collaborator < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :wiki
end
```

Collaborators Table:

```
class CreateCollaborators < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :collaborators do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :wiki, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you try just using the basic functionality of HABTM before you tried to write code that does what it does?

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: It took me a while to understand HABTM / has_many though (they are separate ideas) but the gist is you - create connections between two tables through your intermediary table.  Right now your code is set up to use 'half' a has_many through, set up the other half and you can just write `@user.wikis` and they will be pulled.  Also - decide if you're using HABTM or has_many through - they are separate ideas

Comment: Okay, thank you :)

Comment: No problem - my suggestion is to always check the rails guides - and remember - even though it's 'through' a table - it still creates many of the same methods that has_many / belongs to does directly.  But not all (I've never tried, for instance, to use build across it.  I just did some experimenting in a recipe dummy app - recipe / ingredients - connected through components :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps someone else, this is how I solved my issue:

I added the following into user.rb:

```
has_many :wiki_collaborations, through: :collaborators, source: :wiki
```

and then on my User's show page, I displayed it with:

```
<% @user.wiki_collaborations.each do |collab| %>
  <%= link_to collab.title, wiki_path(collab), :class => 'rq-link' %>
<% end %>
```

Didn't end up needing to use the collect method.